# Auto Suggest in input field using MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0

Actually, i am looking to achieve the auto suggestion in my input field. So i have some set of result in my controller. the code i attached here.

**Contorller**

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        string ProfileUrl = "http://localhost:64413/api/CorporateName/CorporateDetails?pid=" + 5999 + "";
        System.Net.Http.HttpClient DashBoardclient = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();
        DashBoardclient.BaseAddress = new Uri(ProfileUrl);
        DashBoardclient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        DashBoardclient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        HttpResponseMessage dashboardresponseMessage = DashBoardclient.GetAsync(ProfileUrl).Result;
        var DashboardData = dashboardresponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

        JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        List<Corporate> dbresult = (List<Corporate>)jss.Deserialize(DashboardData, typeof(List<Corporate>));

        string GroupID = null;
        string CompanyName = null;

        foreach (Corporate dbresults in dbresult)
        {
            GroupID = dbresults.GroupID;
            CompanyName = dbresults.GroupName;

        }

        return View("Index", dbresult);
    }
```

So, here i am calling the API and stores the result in **dbresult**....The **dbresult** has two parameter(GroupId, GroupName).. **Corporate** is the model

**View Page**

```
@model ClinicSystemMVC.Models.Corporate
        @using (Html.BeginForm())
        {
           @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
           @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.GroupName)
                  <div class="col-sm-9">
                     @Html.EditorFor(model => model.GroupName, new { @class = "form-control" })
                  </div>                            
            </div>
                }
```

I just mentioned only one div which i am expecting to do auto suggest.

**Javascript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
$(document).ready(function () {  
    $("#GroupName").autocomplete({  
        source: function (request, response) {  
            $.ajax({  
                url: "/Home/Index",  
                type: "GET",  
                dataType: "json",  
                data: { Prefix: request.term },  
                success: function (data) {  
                    response($.map(data, function (item) {  
                        return { value: item.GroupName};  
                    }))  

                }  
            })  
        },  
        messages: {  
            noResults: "", results: ""  
        }  
    });  
})
```

With this attached code i cant able to achieve auto suggest. the input field not listing anything. So how can i change my code to achieve auto suggestion in my input field.

Any help appreciated. Thanks in advance !!!

Comment: Your code won't even compile - your passing `List<Corporate>` to a view that expects a single `Corporate`. And what are you attempting to do with your `foreach` loop in the controller - where have you declared `GroupID` and `CompanyName`? (and you do not even use them anyway)

Comment: And the ajax call that is associated with the `autocomplete` needs to call a method that returns a `JsonResult`

Comment: Actually i tried to create another variable to store the result of foreach. But while i tired, it just returns the last value of the loop. The code after foreach loop will look like this:                                                                          var Faclities = new Amenities();
            {
               
                Faclities.GroupID = GroupId;
                Faclities.GroupName= GroupName;
            }

Comment: I'm assuming the view you have shown is not `Index.cshtml`. You `Index()` method needs `return Json(DashboardData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);` (and delete all the code starting at `JavaScriptSerializer jss = ...`

Comment: When i do like that what you mentioned at above. My actual View page is not appearing. It just returns json result in the page @StephenMuecke

Comment: They have to be 2 separate methods!

Comment: Okay. noted with Thanks @StephenMuecke